# Is it better to make separate django models, or add various foreign keys to one model?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model to capture comments from a user, `DocumentComment`. The comments are tied to a particular document in the database, and created/edited/displayed on the page that displays that particular document:

```
class DocumentComment(Model):
   """
   Captures a user's comment about a document
   """
   document_id = models.ForeignKey(Document, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="document file name", related_name='document')
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   comment = models.TextField('comment', blank=True)
   moderated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   added_to_description = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   marked_for_deletion = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False, verbose_name="date created")
   updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False, verbose_name="last update")
```

I now find I need to record comments based on other objects displayed on different pages in the site, e.g. albums (collections of document) is a page and word clouds (derived from all the words in various documents) is another page. Since these new comments are not tied to one document, but a collection of documents, I don't think they should be added to the `DocumentComment` model for every `document_id` in the collection. I wouldn't necessarily want the comments on a collection to be displayed on the page with one of the documents in that collection.

Which approach is better (django-yy or pythonic or idiomatic or by whatever standard you choose):

1. create separate models as above for each display object (i.e. word clouds, albums, maybe more?)
2. keep adding foreign keys to the various objects to the `DocumentComment` model and adding `on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True` to each of the foreign key fields

Also, are there some hidden gotchas about option #2 that I have not thought of?

Thanks!

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model Abstraction is the solution

```
Class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.TextField('comment', blank=True)
    moderated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    added_to_description =  models.BooleanField(default=False)
    marked_for_deletion = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False, verbose_name="date created")
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False, verbose_name="last update")
    Class Meta:
       abstract = True

Class DocumentComment(Comment):
    document_id=Models.ForeignKey()

Class AlbumComment(Comment):
   album_if = Models.ForeignKey()
```

Comment: Thanks! An interesting read - https://dev.to/zachtylr21/model-inheritance-in-django-m0j. One question - Can I move to this design using migrations and preserve the current data in the `DocumentComment` table, or will I have to save off that data with `mysqldump`, delete the table, create the new tables, and then restore the `DocumentComment` table from the `mysqldump` file?

Comment: One drawback to this design is there are 3 admin pages for comments. There is a BooleanField `moderated` for comments to indicate the comment has been moderated and can be displayed on the page, or not. This design has the moderator checking three separate admin pages. Is there a design that allows all the comments to be on one admin page, so a moderator can filter the comments on `moderated=False` and `type=document, or word cloud, or album, or...`? Thanks!

Comment: I think you can do this by [Inline Models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) or You can create your moderation view with combines all 3 models